# Toggle BorderStyle with a method. C#

Tags: c#, .net, methods, properties

Does anybody know how I can write "cardImage1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;" without having to explicitly declare "cardImage1"?

I'm trying to put it into a method so that I don't need to write the code to toggle between two Border Styles when a Picture Box is clicked, for every single single picture box (there are 52!)

e.g. for each box currently I would need to have the following in its _click event.

```
        if (cardImage1.BorderStyle == BorderStyle.None)
        {
            cardImage1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        }
        else
        {
            cardImage1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a handler for each picture box, you could write a single method o handle the clicks for all your picture boxes:

```
 protected void onClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (((PictureBox)sender).BorderStyle == BorderStyle.None)
    {
        ((PictureBox)sender).BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
    }
    else
    {
        ((PictureBox)sender).BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
    }

}
```

You could also write a loop to go over all controls on a form and attac hthe event handler to all picture boxes (if that;s possible in your case)

```
// in your form load event do something like this:
foreach(Control c in this.Controls)
{
    PictureBox pb = c as PictureBox;
    if(pb != null)
       pb.Click += new EventHandler(onClickHandler); // where onClickHandler is the above function
}
```

Of course if you have other picture boxes on the form a solution would be to put the 52 picture boxes you are interested in in a panel and then instead of iterating over all the controls in the form (*this.Controls*) only iterate over the controls in the panel (*thePanelControl.Controls*)

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone, this particular issue is solved and he idea behind it will be used a few more times in the project.

You have no idea how long I was racking my brains about this last night!

Comment: I'm only glad I could help :)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming this is in an event handler, you should cast the `sender` argument to `PictureBox` and operate upon that directly.

```
private void pictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var image = (PictureBox)sender;
    if (image.BorderStyle == BorderStyle.None)
    {
        image.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
    }
    else
    {
        image.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
    }
}
```

You would then use the same event handler on all instances of the `PictureBox`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new type `MyPictureBox` and handle click event. Replace all `PictureBox` with `MyPictureBox`.

```
class MyPictureBox : PictureBox
{
    protected void this_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.BorderStyle == BorderStyle.None)
        {
            this.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        }
        else
        {
            this.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
        }
    }
}
```